# How to write a test for a catched CloneNotSupportedException that never occurs?

Tags: java, mockito

I have this code, written by someone else, and I cannot change it's public signature:

```
@Override
public Rectangle clone() {
    try {
        // super.clone is safe to return since all of the Rectangle's fields are primitive.
        return (Rectangle) super.clone();
    } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
        // should never happen since Cloneable is implemented
        return null;
    }
}
```

The `try` code path is already covered by a unit test.

How do I write a test that covers the `catch` code path?

I tried with

```
@Test(expected = CloneNotSupportedException.class)
public void cloneNotSupportedExceptionTest() {
    Rectangle rectangleMock = mock(Rectangle.class);
    when(rectangleMock.clone())
            .thenThrow(CloneNotSupportedException.class);
    assertThat(rectangleMock.clone()).isNull();
}
```

and all I got was

> java.lang.Exception: Unexpected exception, expected <java.lang.CloneNotSupportedException> but was <org.mockito.exceptions.base.MockitoException>

Comment: The real question is "what is the purpose of testing this?". What if it works and your test assert it's `null` ? What does this test bring to you code robustness? In my opinion nothing, the only way to make it crash is to modify the code in the catch. Is that what you want to look at?
It may be good to have an answer to know how to use mockito, but I don't think you should keep this test.

Comment: You can't do it with Mockito, and I wouldn't invest even a second to figure if PowerMock(ito) could help here. In your example, multiple things come together: A) the code doing what it does relies on things that are "baked" into Java B) it really isn't helpful to test that catch. As the comment says: whether that exception is thrown or not depends on the **structure** of your class. But if someone changes that structure (by dropping that marker interface), your other unit test should fail.

Comment: Okay, that leaves the question "how do I satisfy SonarQube so that it doesn't complain about insufficient coverage on new code", but I will put that in a new question.

Comment: Asked here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57784036/sonarqube-quality-gate-on-new-code-coverage-fails-for-uncovered-code-that-relies