# SonarQube quality gate on new code coverage fails for uncovered code that relies on things baked into Java

Tags: java, unit-testing, sonarqube

Someone on our team changed this code:

```
public class Rectangle implements Cloneable, Serializable {

    @Override
    public Rectangle clone() {
        return new Rectangle(x, y, width, height);
    }

}
```

to this code:

```
public class Rectangle implements Cloneable, Serializable {

    @Override
    public Rectangle clone() {
        try {
            // super.clone is safe to return since all of the Rectangle's fields are primitive.
            return (Rectangle) super.clone();
        } catch (CloneNotSupportedException e) {
            // should never happen since Cloneable is implemented
            return null;
        }
    }

}
```

They wrote a unit test that covers the `try` code path.

They did not write a test that covers the `catch` code path. The `catch` code path relies on things "baked" into Java, the only way to make it crash is to change the *structure* of the class, by dropping the `Cloneable` marker interface. But if that class structure changes, then the other unit test should fail.

Because the `catch` code path isn't covered by a unit test, the SonarQube quality gate "code coverage on new code" fails, and because the quality gate fails, the Jenkins job that builds that branch fails, and because the Jenkins job fails, Bitbucket won't allow the merge.

Already tried:

- FAILED: Mark as false positive in SonarQube: not possible for code coverage quality gate, you can only do that for rule-based issues.
- DIRTY HACK: Turn off (or lower) the quality gate in SonarQube before running the job, and turning it back on after the branch is merged: this works, but it feels so dirty that I think it should happen really exceptionally. I'm looking for a better solution that doesn't require a manual intervention.
- FAILED: Mocking `Rectangle`: won't work, `super.clone()` would have to be mocked, which is on `Object.clone()`, which is a protected method.
- FAILED: Fake it by having an additional class, e.g. `Rectangle` -> `EvilRectangle` -> `TestRectangle`, where `EvilRectangle` throws the `CloneNotSupportedException` and then `TestRectangle` is the actual class instantiated for the test. Won't work because that would change the signature of the `clone()` method, it doesn't throw `CloneNotSupportedException` in `Rectangle`.

**Questions**

- **Java people**:
- How does one write a unit test for the `catch` code path?
- How can the code be rewritten, without changing it's public API, so that it becomes testable?
- **SonarQube people**
- How does one make the quality gate "code coverage on new code" pass?

**EDIT HISTORY**

- added original code

Comment: "How can the code be rewritten, without changing it's public API, so that it becomes testable?" - don't use `clone()`. Refer to "Effective Java" for a discussion as to why.

Comment: Okay, googling "effective java don't use clone". I'll come back for additional questions if I can't figure it out.

Comment: @daniu apparently "Effective Java" is an offline resource (a book).

Comment: Luckily Effective Java isn't the only resource that knows why `clone()` is just a bad idea. You can find plenty of questions on SO about copying objects, where `clone()` may be suggested by someone (and debunked by many others).

Comment: I have added the original code, which did not contain `super.clone()` inside the `clone()` method.

Comment: I found this Dzone article, which mentions alternatives for cloning: https://dzone.com/articles/java-cloning-copy-constructor-vs-cloning

Comment: In addition to solutions presented in your article, you can use an object mapper like Orika https://github.com/orika-mapper/orika

Comment: Now doing an experiment with Apache Commons Lang `SerializationUtils.clone()`, if this works as I hope it does, then I will answer my own question.

Comment: Made the changes in the code, committed, now Jenkins is waiting for an available executor to run the build. Exciting... :-D

Comment: And now SpotBugs complains about `CN_IDIOM_NO_SUPER_CALL`... *sigh* editing `excludeFilterFile`, running job again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apache Commons Lang provides a `clone` method that does a deep copy and does not throw an exception. No exception means no `try/catch` needed, thus one less code path to test. I found this in an article discussing alternatives for `Object.clone()`: https://dzone.com/articles/java-cloning-copy-constructor-vs-cloning

Add this to the `pom.xml`:

```
<dependency>
  <groupId>commons-lang</groupId>
  <artifactId>commons-lang</artifactId>
  <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

Add this to the import statements of your class:

```
import org.apache.commons.lang.SerializationUtils;
```

Your class must have `implements Serializable`. Add a `private static final long serialVersionUID`, that's apparently a best practice.

Then replace `super.clone()` with `SerializationUtils.clone(this)`.

And finally, you can remove the `try/catch` around the `clone()` statement, or remove the `trows` from the method.

This is now my new code:

```
@Override
public Rectangle clone() {
    return (Rectangle) SerializationUtils.clone(this);
}
```

It was already covered by a unit test from before, and that unit test still passes.